# I Completed the Square for x^2-6x, but I don't have the correct x intercepts. How do I find the roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

x^2 -6x when converted into standard form is (x-3)^2 -9

It has a vertex of (3,-9)

It has a y intercept of y = 0

However, I thought the x intercept would be +3. Yet, the book says the x intercepts are (0,6).

How were the "x-intercepts" = "roots" = "solutions" = "zeroes found?

Answer (score 5):

$x$-intercept(s) occur where $y = f(x) = 0$.

$y$-intercept occur where $x=0$.

To find the $y$ intercepts, we simply evaluate $f(0)$. $\;f(0) = 0$.

To find the $x$ intercepts, we set $y = 0$: $$y = x^2 - 6x = 0 \iff x(x-6) = 0 \iff x = 0, \text{ or } x = 6$$

The $x$-intercepts are also the zero's of the *equation* $y = x^2 -6x = 0$ (and so solutions to that *equation*), and they are the roots of the *polynomial* $y = x^2 - 6x$.

Note that since $0$ is both a y-intercept and an x-intercept, the parabola intersects the origin $(0, 0)$

Comment: So I always have to revert to the quadratic expression to find the y and x intercepts? I cannot find them using the standard quadratic equation? Is that correct?

Comment: No need to always use the quadratic equation. For the $y$ intercept, all you do is "plug in" $0$ wherever x occurs, and evaluate. For the $x$ intercepts, you can use the quadratic equation for parabolas (but not when a given function is not a quadratic!), but as you see in this example, we can solve by factoring, in which case, the product is zero if and only if one of the factors is zero.

Comment: My question is why could I not use the zero product property after I completed the square. That would seem logical.

Comment: As I say in my post: $x$-intercepts occur where the function is equal to zero. It so happens that $x^2 - 6x = 0 \iff x(x-6) = 0$, and this happens when $x = 0$ or when $x = 6$.

Comment: Okay, I am just trying to understand this concept thoroughly so as to not forget it when I am tested. Thank You for your help.

Comment: You are welcome, Utveckla!

Comment: As usual, $$\text {Perfect Answer.}$$...(+1)...